# Model vs active records

Tags: yii2

I am a newbie in YII2 and started learning this on my own. Recently I was working on YII2 models. While learning some pre built model files I noticed that some model files are extends through `yii\base\Model` where as some from `\yii\db\ActiveRecord`. 
So I want to know the reason when one should use active records and when model i.e. we can do the query in model too so why is there need of active records. Which are the tasks can be done by active records but not by models. In simple words I want to know specific work of both model and active records.

Comment: ActiveRecord is just a Model (it extends Model) prepared for mapping its data to DB table row and back so you don't have to do all by hand.

Comment: but we can query the data in model too without using active records, so why is there need to active records?

Comment: It's more convenient that way. Read [Active Record guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record).

Comment: ok I am getting it right now, for more info can you please tell me any query which is written differently in model and differently in active record. so I can understand the exact difference. Till now I am thinking both have same query methods. so please give one example and you can put it as answer of my question. thanks.

Comment: If you are not using ActiveRecord you need to use [Query Builder](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder) and [DAO methods](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-dao#non-select-queries) so just compare it with how easy AR is.

Comment: ok thank you so much for your clarification. one last question please, as AR extends Model so everyone would prefer AR over Model. So can you tell me any case where Model could be more preferable than AR.

Comment: [Model](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models) as stated in guide represents business data, rules and logic so it has many purposes. AR offers additional interface for DB source on top of that. How you are using these is up to you. Definitely when there is no need to use DB there is no need to use AR.

Comment: ok! got it now thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveRecord is a `Model` that uses a database engine to store the model(s) data.

`yii\base\Model` is a Model that does not specify how the data is being stored.

Eg a Model could be without a data table and have the actual data stored inside the class code instead of a database. A good example is in the yii2-basic app - the User model [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/models/User.php).

I has the data stored in the class code as:

```
private static $users = [
    '100' => [
        'id' => '100',
        'username' => 'admin',
        'password' => 'admin',
        'authKey' => 'test100key',
        'accessToken' => '100-token',
    ],
    '101' => [
        'id' => '101',
        'username' => 'demo',
        'password' => 'demo',
        'authKey' => 'test101key',
        'accessToken' => '101-token',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Active records use for working with data tables and forms, but yii\base\Models for only for forms.

Comment: but we can also use active records to save form's data.

Comment: A model without a database storage does not mean it should be a form. It might be whatever. It could be a static Model defining the model data in the code. Eg https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/models/User.php